# How to catch client side jQuery validation errors for Kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, kendo-grid

Note: As far as my understanding is correct alternative title could be:

*"How to access the jQuery validator object via client side javascript, what the the Kendo grid uses for row inline edit?"*

**Context**

I can catch (handle) server side validation errors using datasource errors and displaying them in a notification. I would like to display all client side validation errors in a similar notification.

As in the code inhibit shows below it seems to be a standard jQuery validation. Still I do not know how to attach a handler to the existing grid.

**Question**

The client side validation error seems to be **not** triggered the datasource error event.

*How can I write a handler to iterate in client side validation errors and display them in my custom way?*

**Additional info**

Handling server side error is working by handling datasource error event
However this even is not fired when "only" client side validation error occur.

Here is a field causing client side validation error:

[image]

Here is that field's corresponding html with the validation attributes in it:

```
<input class="k-textbox form-control" 
   data-val="true" 
   data-val-length="First Name should be maximum 30 characters" 
   data-val-length-max="30" 
   data-val-regex="Enter at least 3 characters. Use only alphabets and ,.'- characters" 
   data-val-regex-pattern="[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]{3,}" 
   data-val-required="The First Name field is required." 
   id="FirstName" 
   name="FirstName" 
   data-bind="value:FirstName">
```

Comment: So just assume we all know this is probably part of an ASP.NET project and that you may or may not be using the unobtrusive validation plugin?

Comment: Yes. But regardless it is asp or not, the jquery-validate tag in the post and also the html code inhibit with data-val attributes carries that information that the question is jquery validation related. However I have trouble to get the validator object in client side, because kendo inline grid edit masks it pretty deep. So either we reverse engineert kendo to know where is the validator for the inline edit either we found other way to access the validator. I prefer to solve this client side, because I see better chances there.

Comment: I agree we need to focus on client-side.  However, my comment matters because you have not shown us any of the client-side JavaScript or shown us how the `.validate()` method is constructed and called.  Get it now?

Comment: Yes we all get it. (there is no client code, all done by Telerik .js, regardless it is driven from directly javascript or (so it is Kendo UI) or Telerik ASP)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've ended the solution below. *The main issue, how to access the internal jquery validator object of the Kendo grid internal inline form is solved.*  Further refinements are possible.

The following function attached to Kendo grid's "edit" event. I've tried use the grid's "save" or "saveChanges" event but unfortunately neither event fired if jQuery validation error occur in the inline form.

So I am using the validator's validate event itself, and bind the validate handler when the edit event occurs. (It seems the validator created on the fly for the inline form, and not reused.)

The following function attached to Kendo grid's "edit" event:

```
function (e) {
    var validatable = e.sender.editable.validatable;
    validatable.bind("validate", function (e) {
        var errors = e.sender.errors();
            for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                 // do whatever you want with errors[i]
            }
    });
```